# Java Confusing behaviour

Tags: java, string, null, comparison

I was white-box testing some of exception, i came across some confusing behavior , posting sample test code and output!

```
// Use Case #01
String a = null;
System.out.println(" Use Case #01");
System.out.println(" Garbage Testing : "+ a == null );


//Use Case #02
a = null;
System.out.println(" Use Case #02");
System.out.println(" Garbage Testing : " + a != null );
```

Output

> Use Case #01
>
> false
>
> Use Case #02
>
> true

Why is a == null false although a = null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
System.out.println(" Garbage Testing : "+ a == null );
```

*It prints false* and the reason is - it actually comparing `"Garbage Testing : null"==null` which result is  is `false` as `+` is having higher precedence.

proper grouping would solve this problem -

```
System.out.println(" Garbage Testing : "+ (a == null) );
```

Prints -  Garbage Testing : true

```
System.out.println(" Garbage Testing : "+ (a != null) );
```

Prints -  Garbage Testing : false

Comment: Exactly. `+`  have high precedence.

Answer (score 5):

Use brackets for correct behavior:

```
System.out.println(" Garbage Testing : " + (a == null) );
//=>  Garbage Testing : true
```

**Because of [`operators precedence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) where `+` is higher than `==`, your expression is being evaluated as:**

```
System.out.println( (" Garbage Testing : " + a) == null );
```

**and that is false**

**PS:** Also note that in your statement you don't even get `Garbage Testing :` printed.

Comment: thanks, What is the reason behind that , although i know the solution!

Comment: Provided reason also.

Answer (score 2):

'+' operator takes precedence over '=='. In effect, you're comparing the string " Garbage Testing : null" with null. In order to achieve the results you're expecting, you need to place parenthesis around "a == null".

Answer (score 1):

As you are not enclosing

```
a == null
```

in brackets as

```
(a == null)
```

so the left side of the condition in test is actually :

```
" Garbage Testing : "+ a
```

which is definitely NOT null.

There will be no confusion if you test using the brackets as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It makes the summation first then tests for equality. Result of sum is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Once again .. my Team-lead was ahead :) of me in getting the reason ... actually

From Ahsan Bahi
The Reason is that

> [ " Garbage Testing : "+ a  ]

concatenates **" Garbage Testing : "** with **a** value which is **(Null)** so  the final string is

> [ " Garbage Testing : null" ]

and its **comparision with null** is **false**

+1 Ahsan Bahi

+1 Subhrajyoti Majumder, anubhava , Juned Ahsan, Hollis Waite For your effort, thanks